# Do I need when others exception handling for all DML?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exception

I'm quite confused about the best practice regarding handling unknown exceptions in Oracle.

I could do something like this:

```
BEGIN
    --do something
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    raise_application_error etc
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise;
END;
```

This seems to be recommended in a fair few blogs and sites, and is even discussed in the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS99871):

> Avoid unhandled exceptions by including an OTHERS exception handler at
>   the top level of every PL/SQL program.
>
> Make the last statement in the OTHERS exception handler either RAISE
>   or an invocation of the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR procedure. (If you do
>   not follow this practice, and PL/SQL warnings are enabled, then you
>   get PLW-06009.) For information about RAISE or an invocation of the
>   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR, see "Raising Exceptions Explicitly".

But I also know it's been mentioned in a few places that this is fairly horrible to do, e.g. [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1155066278457):

> I truly wish we didn't even support WHEN OTHERS.
>
> You should only catch the exceptions you are expecting and can do
>   something about.  Let  the others propagate out so you can detect them
>   (so you see them)

So my question is simply:

Do I need a *when others* clause which logs and raises *every, single time* I have some use of *data manipulation language* (e.g. an insert/update/delete)? If not, when would I want to avoid it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with anything, it depends.

Generally, my bias would be to only catch those exceptions that you can either handle or that you can add additional information/ context to.  If you know that you have a `SELECT INTO` that may return 0 rows, for example, it makes sense to handle the `no_data_found` exception if you can provide a reasonable default and continue running.  If you can add additional context to the exception, generally by making the text of the error message more meaningful ("Customer cannot be found" rather than "No data found") or by including things like the value of local variables that would be helpful for debugging.

It may make sense to design your code such that you always have a `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler that catches unexpected exceptions, logs them to a table (or a file) along with appropriate context (the values of local variables, for example), **and then re-throws them**.  If you do this consistently, you'll end up with some pretty verbose error logging that gives you a lot of information about the program state at the time an unexpected exception was thrown.  Unfortunately, in the vast majority of cases, the teams that implement and maintain these sorts of systems lose their discipline along the way and the use of `WHEN OTHERS` leads to far less maintainable systems.

If you have a generic `WHEN OTHERS` that does not end with a `RAISE` (or `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`), your code will silently swallow exceptions.  The caller won't know that something went wrong and will continue along thinking that everything is OK.  Inevitably, though, some future step will fail because the earlier silent failure left the system in an unexpected state.  If you have a `WHEN OTHERS` at the end of a large block that has dozens of SQL statements and just a generic `RAISE`, you'll lose the information about what line the actual error occurred on.

Comment: I like this. Currently, I log all expected exceptions and either handle them or raise_application_error them depending on their nature. All my DML has a when others that logs and then calls raise on them. I suppose I could get rid of all the when others, but it would be at the sacrifice of database logging - although there is logging going on in the application layer so perhaps this is an acceptable solution. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @AndrewMartin - Do you have a separate `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler around every DML statement?  Or just one per procedure?  Assuming procedures have multiple statements, a simple `RAISE` causes your error stack to lose the line of the actual error which can make debugging harder.  If you are logging enough information to make it clear where the actual error was, that may not be a big deal.  You may want to use `raise_application_error` to retain the error stack instead.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I currently have a raise_application_error for all expected errors which logs detailed info and then raises them. I also have a when others, currently around each dml statement, which logs them and actually raises them as an application error (with error code -20999, at request of app layer guys).

Comment: So it's handy having a when others around each DML block, as I can log and raise all *unexpected* exceptions - however, if this is bad practice I'd rather not use it. I agree that having one when others block per procedure wouldn't be great, as often mine have multiple DML statements.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - I'd be concerned that raising a single error code for every exception would remove some of the information about the specific error from the error logs.  If everyone knows that they have to check the database `error_log` table to see what actually happened and the support folks can correlate the application logs to the database logs, that may be a reasonable trade-off.  If everyone maintaining the system can have the same discipline, and the code remains readable with all the exception handling lines, I'd have no objection.  It's just a tough discipline to maintain.

Comment: Again, I should be clearer. I raise everything with -20999, and then in the message concatenate the actual error code and the actual error message (from Oracle). I lost the fight on that one and the app layer guys want it that way. I think I'm happy proceeding with when others blocks for now, just to ensure all errors are getting logged and handled or raised.

Comment: A further question with this. If I had Procedure 1 calling Procedure 2 and a when others block in Procedure 2 where I logged and then raised an error - how would I stop Procedure 1 re-handling this once the error was raised? I wouldn't want to *relog* it, I would just want to continue raising it.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - You can't.  Both procedures would log the error (presumably along with whatever context each procedure has).  That leads to pretty verbose error logs but you'll have a lot of information about the state of every procedure in the call stack.

Comment: Is it worth considering having one outer when others block in the parent procedure then, and letting any unexpected procedures simply propogate to there, where they can be logged with a full stacktrace and raised? Or would you consider that dangerous as you could potentially raise an exception several layers before you actually deal with it (i.e. log it and raise it)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70886/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-andrew-martin).

Answer (score 1):

Catching all unhandled exceptions at a particular tier can be appropriate in these scenarios(likely not a complete list):

- You want to log the exception and then rethrow it.
- You want to rethrow it with a more specific contextual error message.  For example you might want to provide a message that provides information such as what parameters were passed to the procedure.
- You want to hide the details from the caller.  Perhaps due to security concerns and want to ensure an application doesn't have access to the real exception that might reveal sensitive details.

If these procedures are called from an application, it is probably best to let all of them bubble up to the application, and let the application decide where/when to handle/log/wrap them.

Usually the application employs a similar technique. It often has a handler for all unhandled exceptions, logs the full exception/stack, and then wraps them in a generic error to display to the user, thus hiding potentially sensitive information from the original error, and providing the user more concrete direction such as "If errors persist, contact support".

**Here's where you can cause headaches for application programmers:**
You catch an exception at the SP layer, then rethrow a generic error.  While it's always best to code defensively and avoid exceptions, sometimes the application programmer has no choice but to literally `try`, knowing that in certain circumstances an exception will occur, and then write code specifically to handle it.  If you wrap the exception in a generic exception, then the programmer can't address specific error scenarios, because you've hid them all under the same bucket.  Additionally, the log at the application level would usually contain the full stack trace, and at the deepest level will be the error bubbled up from the database call, which will be wrapped in your generic error thus hiding away what the true cause of the problem was.  This can be a huge problem when trying to address difficult to reproduce errors, and you really need detailed logs that allow you to see the true error so you have an idea of what the problem might be.

Of course not all app programmers will think that way, because they don't all employ the same technique.  However, any decent programmer should know how to wrap the errors that come from the database in a generic fashion, if that is what they choose to do.  Unwrapping exceptions on the other hand is often more difficult or impossible depending on what was omitted when they were original wrapped.  This is why IMO it's better to err on the side of not wrapping exceptions until you are at the layer that interacts with the user.

Comment: So I could effectively leave the when others off all the time and if an error occurs allow the application to fail and allow the exception handling and logging at the application layer deal with everything? That would leave me to log only expected exceptions in the database. Or does this introduce another layer of bad practice, having logging going on at separate levels (expected in db, unexpected at app layer)?

Comment: @AndrewMartin I would not log at the DB level(but catch/swallow scenarios that we don't consider an error, such as certain no_data's), because if an unexpected DB exception occurs from an app, we will want to see the full stack of app+DB in the app log, rather than jump between a DB log.  **However, perhaps, as the database programmer you want to be made aware of errors so you can investigate on your own and stay on top of potential bugs in your SP's.** That would be a good reason to log at DB, if that is in fact your goal.  I'd still bubble the exceptions though if they aren't handled.

Answer (score 0):

While Tom Kyte is a brilliant man with a vast knowledge of Oracle, he is, where the rubber meets the road, still just a DBA. So while I would never dream of arguing with him on matters of tuning queues or the best layout of tablespaces or the best way to resolve deadlocks, his discourses on programming may freely be taken with a grain of salt. Or two.

Why do we ever want to fool around with exceptions at all? In answering this question, we must realize that exceptions fall into two broad categories:

1. Exceptions we expect. Generally, exceptions raised by system or user routines we call.
2. Exceptions we don't expect. Generally, exceptions raised by the system when some primitive operation goes awry -- like dividing by zero.

When we design any kind of database stored procedure (or even a class method in Java or C#) there may be certain minimum inputs and function states our code needs to work properly. If the caller has not provided enough inputs, or the wrong kind of inputs, or has failed to, say, open the correct channel to some I/O stream, it may be impossible for the code to operate and this failure cannot be ignored. When that happens, we want to let the caller know what happened so they may take corrective actions.

Now we may not know which code calls our code or under what circumstances or what effect our inability to operate will have on it's own operation. So we raise a meaningful exception that allows it to respond as *its* developer deems appropriate.

As that is true of our routine, it is also true of any routine we call. Let's take the simple example (in generic SQL syntax) of a procedure that creates a table of a specified name and structure.

```
procedure CreateTable( varchar tableName, varchar fieldDefs ) as begin
    DropTable( tableName );
    exec immediate 'create table ' || tableName || '(' || fieldDefs || ');';
end procedure;
```

What can go wrong? First, the `tableName` argument could be null or the string it contains does not properly form a legal table name or there may already exist a table of that name or the user does not have the permissions to create a table. Second, the `fieldDefs` argument also could be null or the string it contains does not properly form the field definitions.

Do we have to spend the first few lines of code checking for all these possibilities. Maybe. At a minimum it would be nice to check for a null required argument and raise a meaningful exception.

```
procedure CreateTable( varchar tableName, varchar fieldDefs ) as begin
    if tableName is null or fieldDefs is null then
        raise NULL_ARGUMENT;
    end if
    DropTable( tableName );
    exec immediate 'create table ' || tableName || '(' || fieldDefs || ');';
end procedure;
```

Now our routine calls another routine. We know the argument we are passing to it is not null but there could be other problems. Or the table may not exist. If the table does not exist, we want to ignore that exception but if there is something bogus about the contents of the argument, we will discover that when we use it to create the table and error messages involving table creation will make more sense from a routine named "CreateTable" then something involving dropping tables. So we elect to ignore those too. This is where `others` comes in handy.

```
procedure CreateTable( varchar tableName, varchar fieldDefs ) as begin
    if tableName is null or fieldDefs is null then
        raise NULL_ARGUMENT;
    end if
    begin
        DropTable( tableName );
    exception
        when others then
           ; -- ignore
    end;
    exec immediate 'create table ' || tableName || '(' || fieldDefs || ');';
end procedure;
```

Now we will want to have an exception handler where we examine each possible source of failure mentioned above, which has to have come from the create table statement (or our own NULL_ARGUMENT) and raise our own meaningful exception back out to our caller.

But this is far enough for our purposes. Let's examine what we would have to do if there were no `when other` option available. We would have to test for every conceivable exception just to ignore them all

```
when this then
    ; --ignore
when that then
    ; --ignore
when something then
    ; --ignore
when something_else then
    ; --ignore
when something_else_entirely then
    ; --ignore
when one_in_a_million_longshot then
    ; --ignore
```

This is cumbersome to say the least. Even when we want to catch some specific exceptions and re-raise our own for clarity but ignore the rest, we still have to append most of this huge list to every exception handler. Do we ever miss one? Let's hope not because if we do, and it is ever raised, we loose control over the entire exception handling operation.

No, despite what you may have heard, the ability to specify that we want to handle "all other heretofore unspecified exceptions" mitigates too many programming issues to be ignored.

Can it be misused? Of course. Any feature of any language and any tool in any tool chest can be misused. That's a flimsy excuse to chuck the feature or the tool.

Answer (score 0):

WHEN OTHERS is certainly an important part of pl/sql when used correctly.  In general I do not recommend a WHEN OTEHRS for every DML.  Instead we keep track of where we are in the program with 'func_no' - a simple hard coded value that changes with each DML and usually other critical points in the code.  We also keep track of useful info as it changes within the program. That is not just - 'Creating Invoice.',   but  "Creating invoice, customer= '||rec.customer_number||', invoice no: '||to_char(invoice_number);

My recommendation is to handle expected data conditions explicitly using NO_DATA_FOUND, TOO_MANY_ROWS, DIVIDE_BY_ZERO, etc along with testing within data using SQL%ROWCOUNT, etc.

I only use 1 WHEN OTHERS per program unit.  It is in the outer block.  It contains the func_no and the data specific message along with the error stack and the backtrace, normally does a rollback, and always does a RAISE;